# How do I align a photo next to text within a heading using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way that I can position the circle on the right of the heading in line with the text?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPdrl.png)

This is my code:

```css
.header {
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #7e8f94;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.brand_logo_container2 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>Information Centre</p>
  <div class="brand_logo_container2">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated : )

Comment: One way is to  use `display: flex;` in your header class & delete that extra div.clearfix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.header p{width:50%;display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: .header p{display:inline;}

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be to give the `<p>` element a `float: left`